# How do I change the color of the PaneToggleButton in a UWP NavigationView?

Tags: uwp, hamburger-menu

I am trying to change color of the hamburger button in a NavigationView. I can change the colors of the NavigationViewItems and the Buttons, but the code below does not change the PaneToggleButton.

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="controls:NavigationViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
 </Page.Resources>
```

Revised code below fixed the issue

```
 <controls:NavigationView.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForeground" Color="White"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver"Color="Yellow"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed"Color="LightGreen"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected"Color="White"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Orange"/>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed" Color="Pink"/>
 </controls:NavigationView.Resources>

 <controls:NavigationView.PaneToggleButtonStyle>
     <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonStyle}">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
      </Style>
  </controls:NavigationView.PaneToggleButtonStyle>
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomNavigationMenuStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#C21334" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

 <NavigationView x:Name="nvMainLevelNavigation"                     
                PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal" 
                IsSettingsVisible="false"
                Header="Title"
                PaneToggleButtonStyle="{StaticResource CustomNavigationIconStyle}"
                ItemInvoked="nvMainLevelNavigation_ItemInvoked"
                SelectionChanged="nvMainLevelNavigation_SelectionChanged"
                Loaded="nvMainLevelNavigation_Loaded">
 </NavigationView>
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Open your project in **Blend** and in the designer select the **NavigationView**, then click the option to edit the style of **PaneToggleButton** there you can edit the style of the toggle button and make any changes as you wish including changing the **ForeGround** then assign that style to the NavigationView like :

```
<NavigationView PaneToggleButtonStyle="{StaticResource styleResourceKey}"/>
```

> For design purposes, **generic.xaml** is available in the (Program Files)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10586.0\Generic folder from a Windows SDK installation.

You can find the **PaneToggleButtonStyle** in this file, so if you do not want to use blend, just find that style in this file and copy paste it into your project and then edit it as you like and apply it to your navigation view.

Comment: Many thanks. I added revised code above to my NavigationView xaml.